# Problem sharing ethernet connection via WiFi

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet

I've an Ethernet connection to the Internet and I need to share it via Wifi with my other mobile devices. I followed up the instructions of setting up a hotspot in Ubuntu:

1. I created a new connection via the network manager tool.
2. I setup the security options: WEP 128 Encryption Passphrase.
3. I turned on the hotspot using this new connection.
4. My laptop connected successfully to the hotspot, however it didn't appear when I activated Wifi on the other device (Android devices).

What is the problem?

Comment: WEP is insecure. Please consider using WPA2. Also try to disconnect the laptop and connect the android device alone (just to check that there is no weird conflict between the two)

Comment: Thank you hmayag for the security information. I deleted the previous connection and created a new one with WPA security. But even when disconnecting the laptop from the hotspot WiFi connection, it doesn't appear on my Android devices ?!

Comment: Can you give us a more detailed description of your setup? It is not clear whether your hot-spot is a stand-alone router or a wi-fi card on your computer. Also please add make/model of devices if possible.

Comment: My hotspot is setup over the WiFi interface. I followed the simplest way to add it via the GUI-based networking manager. I tried to connect an Android 4.1.1 running on a Samsung Galaxy Tab2.

Comment: I checked the spec list of samsung tab2 and it supports all of b/g/n networks. Since your wifi setup is working with your laptop, your issue sounds like a hardware problem on the side of the tablet. Can you detect other networks in the area? Have you connected it to other wifi networks successfully?

Comment: Yes of course. The tablet can detect other WiFi network nearby and I used to connect it to other WiFi networks. Is there a specific options to set when creating connections? I mean infrastructure or adhoc?

Comment: Your wifi card (on the computer) should be set to infrastructure mode and your other devices should be set to ad-hoc mode. Edit: Sorry,all devices should be set to the same mode!

Answer (score 1):

You have created an adhoc network. 
To share wifi to your android device, you need to create a wifi-hotspot